# wsgi with python3.4 and python2.7

Tags: python, django, apache2

my computer have python3.4 and python2.7(default), django1.9 running in apache2,how can I let wsgi.py run with python3.4?

when I do `sudo service apache2 start` and open `127.0.1.1` in the browser, it's waring, and in error.log : `ImportError: No modul e named django.core.wsgi` so I know `wsgi.py` runing by python2.7 but it need python3.4 .

in `manage.py` and `wsgi.py` header add `#!usr/bin/python3` but not work .(`python3` in my computer can running python3.4)

how can I let `wsgi.py` running with python3.4?????

Answer (score 1):

Couple things to try:

Your first line is looking at the relative path so that is a problem, but not necessarily the problem, fix it as such:

```
#!usr/bin/python3
```

to

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
```

if that doesn't work try to install wsgi via pip in python3

```
python3 -m pip install wsgi
```

Comment: let me try this night!!!   thank you

Comment: `python3 -m pip install wsgi` not working

Comment: Need more, what about it doesn't work?  Do you get an error message?

Are you typing that at the command line?